# split file based on multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, hadoop, split, apache-pig

Is it Possible to split a file based on multiple delimiters using Pig

example: I have a file as below

```html
abc|123>xyz:amd<yts
abd|124>xyz:amc<yts
```

is it possible to split based on  |,>,:,< and get the output stored as

```html
abc|123|xyz|amd|yts
abd|124|xyz|amc|yts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easier to capture what you want instead of splitting using this pattern

```
([^|>:<]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/224)